# How can I disable autosave in Excel and Word through Intune?

Tags: office365, intune, autosave, user-enrollment

I have a question/problem regarding turning off Autosave through Intune. (Not sure if this is the correct topic, but I couldn't find one that matched)

I want to disable autosave by default in Excel and Word, but the configuration settings doesn't have any effect. Is there any way that you could turn autosave off and enroll it through intune?

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: Sounds like a non-programming question. I'd suggest posting this to the https://www.superuser.com web site instead.